# save the output of the keydown

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I catch the event down, but I need to save the clicked buttons.

for example a way to get modifiers + e.key

This is my code:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {       
            //base.OnKeyDown(e);
            if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
            }    
        }
```

I tried to combine two keys like

```
 Key test = Key.Ctrl | e.Key ;
```

but it always give wrong results , for exampl Ctrl + E result in due to the above code to J

I want to save it, and I want to make those shortcuts general in all `UserControls`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using [KeyGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611296.aspx):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key ==Key.E && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers==ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        KeyGesture keyGesture = new KeyGesture(e.Key, e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers);
        if (keyGesture.Matches(null, e))
        {
            //This should match!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this but I want to save the result of SHift +E in variable Key

Comment: Edited my answer, a bit contrived example perhaps.

Comment: KeyGesture is applicable only @ silverlight 5

Comment: I guess you could write your own. But it would be nice if it was out-of-the-box of course.

Comment: can e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers carry for example ctrl , and shift

Comment: According to the doc the e.[KeyBoardDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.aspx) is the current [KeyboardDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboarddevice.aspx)
If you write your own keygesture you can find inspiration [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/KeyGesture@cs/1305600/KeyGesture@cs)

Answer (score 0):

ok as I use silverlight4 , I will use

```
Tuple<ModifierKeys, Key>
```

it work great and its performance is great